# Расширяемая область Layout

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать вот такую штуку в android java:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раздел Wi-Fi меняется ширина, при нажатии на разделительную линию и движением пальца по экрану, как это реализовать

Comment: Возможно вам нужен `SlidingPaneLayout`

Comment: @pavlofff это штука, Sliding layout , наверное,  хорошая, но там, как  понл нужно испоьзовать фрагменты  (пример от Климова), а у мен достаточно сложные объект. Нужен слайдинг между Recycle view и ScrollViee, если это можно реализовать, положите пожалуйста пример куда-нибудь сюда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два горизонтальных LinearLayout которые находятся в одном вертикальном LinearLayout (Разметку внутри них делаешь какую надо). И создаешь класс который обрабатывает нажатие на горизонтальный LinearLayout. Получаешь координаты и можешь вычислить на сколько касание отходит от разделительной линии. Если это расстояние устраивает(Зависит от того какую чувствительность делать) то можно уже через setlayout width уюавлять и прибавлять заначение. В зависимости от координат пальца

Comment: Я подобную штуку делал, но это получается как-то топорно, там библий никаких нет?

Comment: @KostyaM Возможно и есть...Но я о ней не знаю. Даже если есть, то наверняка реализована подобным образом. Плюсом еще будет море разных лишних функций.